# Не отображается JScrollPane в JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

При нажатии на кнопку , программа читает файл и выводит данных про количество слов в нем в список, далее список помещается в JScrollPane , но проблема в том ,  что список не отображается или не отображается сама панель.Точно сказать не могу в чем проблема, прошу у вас помощи.Но есть одна особенность , если в поле JScrollPane провести колесом мыши , то список появится.

```
    JList list = new JList(data);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    list.setFont( new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16) );
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    panel.add( scroll ).setBounds(50,250,300,300);
```

На панели все находится. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если панель уже видна на экране в момент добавления, вызовите `scroll.revalidate()` после `setBounds`, чтобы он переразместил свои внутренние компоненты (`JList`) в соответствии с новыми размерами.